# Laravel cookies error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cookies

I'm having problems creating a cookie with laravel, the thing is that sometimes the value of this cookie changes into a `null` intead of its real value which makes my system give errors that I've programed to show in case this cookie dont exist.

This happens when a reaload the page, I've debugged with `dd()` and every time that I reload the page the value changes from'activo' to 'null' and from 'null' to 'activo', why does this happen?

My code:

```
public function store_inicio(Request $request)
{

    $empresa_id = $request->input('empresa_id');
    $empresa = Empresa::find($empresa_id);
    $cierre = $empresa->inicio_caja()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();
    if (isset($cierre)) {
        if (!isset($cierre->cierre)) {
            Cookie::queue('estado_caja', 'activo', 180);
            Cookie::queue('numero_caja', $cierre->caja, 180);

        } else {
            $this->crear_inicio($request, $empresa);
        }
    } else {
        $this->crear_inicio($request, $empresa);
    }

    return redirect('ventas');

}

private function crear_inicio($request, $empresa)
{
    $aux_usuario = $request->input('usuario_inicio_caja');
    $usuario = User::where('name', $aux_usuario)->first();
    $numero_caja = $request->input('caja_inicio_caja');
    $valor = $request->input('valor_inicio_caja');
    $inicio_caja = new Inicio_caja();
    $inicio_caja->user_id = $usuario->id;
    $inicio_caja->caja = $numero_caja;
    $inicio_caja->valor = $valor;
    $inicio_caja->save();
    $empresa->inicio_caja()->syncWithoutDetaching($inicio_caja->id);
    Cookie::queue('estado_caja', 'activo', 600);
    Cookie::queue('numero_caja', $numero_caja, 600);
}
```

Comment: Which method you have problem with? `store_inicio` or `crear_inicio`? Because they both set cookies. Seems like sometimes `$cierre->caja` and `$numero_caja` is null. Start debugging from here. Also checking `isset($cierre)` doesn't guarant you that `$cierre->caja` exists.

Comment: @Tarasovych Hi thx for answering, both methods makes almost the same thing, the `store_inicio` calls the `crear_inicio` if the users wants to create a new session and the `ifs` just take care if the currens session isnt closed, just giving more time creating the same cookies to continue the user's operation, the thing is that these methos work just fine, the problem is with the cookies and with the `estado_caja`. it is created perfectly but its value changes when the page is reloaded, and i dont have any method that do that

Comment: Strange, `Cookie::queue()` for `estado_caja` doesn't have dynamic values from variables or so. So cookie might be set with `activo` value of not set at all.

Comment: @Tarasovych hey I've fixed it haha, there's a problem with `php artisan serve` its like it doesnt recognize some routes so I started using laragon, as simple as that and it took me several days to realize there isnt a problem at all